# I can't change the Host header using reverse proxy

Tags: go

I'm building a reverse proxy for my backend but I can't understand why even if I change the host header with any method I've seen in the documentation It won't change.
The backend need the real host in order to serve the right content.

Here is the code:

```
proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{
    Director: func(req *http.Request) {
        targetURL := url.URL{
            Scheme: "http",
            Host:   "backend.com",
            Path:   req.URL.Path,
        }

        req.URL.Scheme = targetURL.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = targetURL.Host
        req.URL.Path = targetURL.Path
        req.Header.Set("Host", targetURL.Host)

    },
    Transport: transport,
}

// Listen on a local port and serve the reverse proxy without buffer method
server := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "localhost:8080",
    Handler: proxy,
}
fmt.Println("Listening on :8080...")
err = server.ListenAndServe()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use [(*ProxyRequest).SetURL](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#ProxyRequest.SetURL) added in go1.20, it will be as easy as:

```golang
proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{
    Rewrite: func(pr *httputil.ProxyRequest) {
        targetURL := url.URL{
            Scheme: "http",
            Host:   "backend.com",
            Path:   req.URL.Path,
        }
        pr.SetURL(&targetURL)
    },
    Transport: transport,
}
```

See this proposal for more information: [net/http/httputil: replace Director with Rewrite](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53002).

---

In the case that it's impossible to upgrade to go1.20, here is a workaround for the `Director`:

```
  proxy := &httputil.ReverseProxy{
    Director: func(req *http.Request) {
        targetURL := url.URL{
            Scheme: "http",
            Host:   "backend.com",
            Path:   req.URL.Path,
        }

        req.URL.Scheme = targetURL.Scheme
        req.URL.Host = targetURL.Host
        req.URL.Path = targetURL.Path
-       req.Header.Set("Host", targetURL.Host)
+       req.Host = targetURL.Host
+       // or simply:
+       // req.Host = ""
    },
    Transport: transport,
  }
```

See the doc for [http.Request.Host](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request):

> For client requests, Host optionally overrides the Host header to send. If empty, the Request.Write method uses the value of URL.Host.

Comment: It works and I will use this from now on, thanks. But I also want to understand why it wasn't working before, can you explain what I was missing?

Comment: That's because `req.Host` has higher priority. See my updated answer. BTW, I haven't tested the workaround for the Director. Can you have a test and feedback in the comment? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I confirm that it works with req.Host = "" or req.Host = "backend.com". Thank you!